# Convert to input box from span tag and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a span tag to an input box and vice versa on a web app I'm building. I can convert the span tag to an input box and back but for some reason if you click the span tag a second time it does not convert it to an input box. I can only assume this is because of the binding and unbinding of handlers in jQuery but I cannot work out the best way to handle this functionality. Any ideas?

```
$('[content-editable]').click(function(){

    var edit_box = $(this);

    $(edit_box).html('<input type="text" content-editing value="' + $(edit_box).html() + '">');

    $(edit_box).find('input').select();

    setTimeout(function(){

        $('body').on('click', function(){

            $(edit_box).html($(edit_box).find('input').val());

        });

    }, 500);

});
```

ps. The timeout was added to stop the input box becoming a span tag directly after clicking it.

My JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AaxT9 - For some reason in JS Fiddle it does not convert it back to span tag after clicking the body but it does in my web app.

Comment: Please share your JSFiddle so we can help you out.

Comment: If you already making your `span` `contenteditable` then why do you need to convert it to input?

Comment: Added the JSFiddle although it does not handle my JavaScript 100%.

Comment: I'm using the content-editable attribute purely as a unique selector. Nothing more.

Comment: So you want to make it edittable only for 0.5 sec?

Comment: Once the span is converted to an input box, it usually turns it straight back into a span tag. Hence the timeout of 500ms was added to stop it doing this. Because the input box is being dynamically loaded with Javascript and isn't there on body load I need to bind the handler to the code.

Comment: @BradBird : Did you try out my solution? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your try:

1. You are putting handler in wrong place. Keeping it inside another click handler will assign handler multiple times and incrementaly call handler.
2. You may want to click somewhere else to convert it back to span. So go with `document` click bind.
3. Also, keep your code inside `$(document).ready()` function to ensure DOM has been loaded.

Do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var edit_box = $('[content-editable]');
    $(document).on("click",function() {
        console.log($(event.target));
        if($(event.target).is("[content-editable]")) {
            $(edit_box).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(edit_box).html() + '">');
            $(edit_box).find('input').select();
        }
        else if(!$(event.target).is("input")){
            $(edit_box).html($(edit_box).find('input').val());   
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AaxT9/6/)**

I have `document` click for my part but if you want to use `body` click handler then you may use it, but this will convert `input` back to `span` only on `body` clicks.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting the time out move the code to change back to `span` within the `onblur` function of the input appended.

**Code**

```
$('[content-editable]').click(function () {
    var edit_box = $(this);
    $(edit_box).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(edit_box).html() + '">');
    $(edit_box).find('input').select().on('blur', function () {
        $(edit_box).html($(edit_box).find('input').val());
    });
});
```

---

**Edit**

```
$('[content-editable]').click(function () {
    var edit_box = $(this);
    $(edit_box).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(edit_box).html() + '">');
    $(edit_box).find('input').select().one('blur', function () {
        $(edit_box).html($(edit_box).find('input').val());
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AaxT9/7/)

Comment: But, this will cause problem as you are assigning `blur` handler on every click... And in your fiddle, if you click on input again, then see what happens... It replaces input value with wrong data...

Comment: @j809 I didn't see that while testing. Since your removing that `input` every time I think that issue may not occur. Won't changing `on` to `one` solve the issue?